# Winform UserControl and wpf WindowsFormHost: UserControl goes off the edge of the WindowsFormHost

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windowsformshost

For some reason, I can't get my Winform usercontrol to fit inside of the WindowsFormsHost. Here's the xaml that I am using:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="326*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="300*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="264*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <WindowsFormsHost   Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="0">
    <winforms:ServicesUserControl x:Name="servicesUserControl"
                                  UserCanEditRevenue="True"
                                  BorderStyle="Fixed3D">
    </winforms:ServicesUserControl>
  </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

Here's a screenshot to show what I mean:

Here is the original user control:
[image]

But when I put it in a WindowsFormHost I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the UserControl has its own logic to resize the columns, the width of the UserControl will be bound to the width of its columns. I would try implementing the WinFormsHost inside a ScrollViewer, if that will be an acceptable layout.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0">
  <WindowsFormsHost>
    <winforms:ServicesUserControl x:Name="servicesUserControl"
                                  UserCanEditRevenue="True"
                                  BorderStyle="Fixed3D" />
  </WindowsFormsHost>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I'm gonna give you this answer because of what you first said.  It fixed my problem in a roundabout way.  I ended up going to the original user control and resizing the grid control in it to fit the complete user control and tweeked the Dock and Location properties.  That worked.